# Update database when I submit button HTML / PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create form where I have text which I can edit and save to database for later use it in other file.
I wrote following code, text is showing great from database , but updating text by submit button don't work.

It is strange but after submit, echo "Successfully saved!" normally displays, but not updating.

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "db", "password", "db");
$query = "SELECT text FROM mailtext";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $text = iconv('iso-8859-2', 'utf-8', $row['text']);
    echo'
<center>
    <form id="mailtext" method="post">
        <textarea name="text" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">'.$text.'</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</center>
';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query2 = "UPDATE mailtext SET text='.$text.' WHERE id=1";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        echo 'Successfully saved!';
    }
}
```

If you have any question or something like this, please ask :)
Yes, I tried to searching answers in other questions, but nothing helped.

Comment: Why all rows from `mailtext` is selected and only updated one ?

Comment: Have you checked for errors occuring during the update? Have you thought about using code that is not widely open to SQL injection?

Comment: @SmitMehta I updated only one rows, because I have only one rows in `mailtext`.

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean about code not widely open to SQL injection? I am not perfect in this.

Comment: You should google that term quickly if you don't know it yet: just image what would happen if `$text` contained a single quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are submitting your form, the page is reloaded with the content of `$_POST` and is re-executed from top to bottom.

```
//            Form is submitted
// You are getting the content of the table
//                  |
//                  |
//                  V
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "db", "password", "db");
$query = "SELECT text FROM mailtext";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
//      You are displaying the form
//                  |
//                  |
//                  V
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $text = iconv('iso-8859-2', 'utf-8', $row['text']);
    echo'
<center>
    <form id="mailtext" method="post">
        <textarea name="text" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">'.$text.'</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</center>
';
// You are treating the previously submitted form
//                  |
//                  |
//                  V
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query2 = "UPDATE mailtext SET text='.$text.' WHERE id=1";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        echo 'Successfully saved!';
    }
}
```

You have to treat the form **before** querying the database to get the informations, otherwise, the datas won't be inserter/updated.

Note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. I suggest you to use parameterized queries

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "db", "password", "db");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE mailtext SET text=? WHERE id=1";
    //                                  ^------------------- Set a parameter for the query
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query2);
    //      ^------------^---------------------------------- Prepare the query for parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $text);
//  ^--------------------^---------------------------------- bind the parameters
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//  ^-----------------^------------------------------------- execute the safe query
    echo 'Successfully saved!';
}

$query = "SELECT text FROM mailtext";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $text = iconv('iso-8859-2', 'utf-8', $row['text']);
    echo'
<center>
    <form id="mailtext" method="post">
        <textarea name="text" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">'.$text.'</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</center>
';
}
```

Comment: this script is okay but it will created multiple forms equal to number of rows in the mailtext table. Isn't that incorrect ?

Comment: Now its okay. Great!

Comment: @SmitMehta still not, I fixed some comments

Comment: Oh well, in fact it will submit only 1 form, even if there is many of them

Comment: Yes, true. But that will updated that row whose id equals to 1 everytime regardless whichever of the form is submitted.

Comment: @Cid ok, it's updated great, but it destroyed this line `$text = iconv('iso-8859-2', 'utf-8', $row['text']);` - do you have idea how repair showing and updating with special chars?